# Replace URL query string parameter value in form action using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following form

```
<form action="http://www.domain.com/processing.php?page=first&section=77&userid=replaceme">
```

how using jquery can I update 'replaceme' with a jquery variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use a regular expression and match the name of the "userid" parameter, rather than the "replaceme" value.

Try:

```
var $form = $('form');
$form.prop('action', $form.prop('action').replace(/([\?&])(userid=)[^&#]*/, '$1$2' + newValue));
```

Where `newValue` is a variable holding what you want in place of "replaceme".

Note: In your html, the "&" characters in the URL should be replaced with the character entity `&amp;`.

**UPDATE:**

Using the suggestion from @undefined, this would be:

```
$('form').prop('action', function(i, action){ return action.replace(/([\?&])(userid=)[^&#]*/, '$1$2' + newValue); });
```

Now there's no need for the `$form` variable.

Here's a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/AsGc9/3/) showing the following cases:

1. The "userid" parameter is the last parameter, after at least one other parameter.
2. The "userid" parameter is the middle parameter, with a parameter before it and another after it.
3. The "userid" parameter is the first parameter, with others after it.
4. There is a parameter with a name that ends with "userid", which should not be replaced.
5. There is a #tag at the end of the URL, just after the "userid" parameter.

Explanation of the regular expression:

- The first group `$1` matches a '?' or '&'.
- The second group `$2` matches 'userid='.
- Then characters are matched until either an '&' or '#' is reached or until the end of the string.

Comment: +1 For using `prop` and `regex`. You can also pass a function to `prop` method, `$('form').prop('action', function(i, action){ return action.replace('..', '...'); })`.

Answer (score 2):

First add an ID:

```
<form id="myForm" action="http://www.domain.com/processing.php?page=first&section=77&userid=replaceme">
```

Then on DOM ready:

```
$(function() {
    var $form = $('#myForm');
    var someVar = 'foo';
    $form.attr('action', $form.attr('action').replace('replaceme', someVar));
});
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/HBQcx/

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you have the following markup:

```
  <form id="testform" action="http://www.domain.com/processing.php?page=first&section=77&userid=replaceme">
</form>
```

and you want to change some text in the `action` attribute ::

```
action = $('#testform').attr('action');//get the action attribute.
console.log(action);
action = action.replace('replaceme','changed');//change the action text.
$('#testform').attr('action',action);//change the action attribute.
console.log($('#testform').attr('action'));//test the results.
```